# RDF4J Workbench: Why is One SPIN Constructor Very Slow?

Tags: sparql, rdf, sesame, topbraid-composer, rdf4j

I apologize for the length of this posting.  I am trying to make this slow rule issue reproducible.

I'm using TopBraid Composer FE to create an RDF file with ontology and SPIN constructors.  He purpose of the SPIN constructors is to check for compliance in the instantiations of individuals of classes defined in the ontology.  I find that the execution of the SPIN constructor is very slow, and I'd like to know why.

[Ontology Including SPIN Constructors SXXIComplianceCheck18.rdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5rex-PdunMsdkxMUm1faFdsTDA/view?usp=sharing)

I Modify/Clear my repository (an In Memory Store with RDFS+SPIN support) and load this ontology into RDF4J workbench:[image: RDF4J Workbench System Information]

[image]

[image]

Next, I use two SPARQL Update queries in sequence to created individuals of classes defined in the ontology (RDF file above) and thus stimulate running SPIN constructors.

First SPARQL Update query (instantiates individual data items and invokes parsing constructors as needed... runs quickly):

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sxxicc: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheck#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX sp: <http://spinrdf.org/sp#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX smf: <http://topbraid.org/sparqlmotionfunctions#>
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX spl: <http://spinrdf.org/spl#>
PREFIX spin: <http://spinrdf.org/spin#>
PREFIX arg: <http://spinrdf.org/arg#>
PREFIX SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals#>
PREFIX sxxicci: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>


INSERT DATA
{
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem110 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem110 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "(C) M221.5"^^xsd:string .  
  
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem500 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem500 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "S181"^^xsd:string .
  
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem300 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem300 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "DC"^^xsd:string .
  
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem113 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem113 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "FX"^^xsd:string .
      
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem511 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem511 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "SIGHT SEEING"^^xsd:string .

   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem501 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem501 ;
#            sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "M002"^^xsd:string .
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "M018,     160727"^^xsd:string .
  
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem503 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem503 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "CUBESAT, TOM"^^xsd:string .
           
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504a a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem504 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "FAS Agenda line 1"^^xsd:string ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasOrdinalNumber "1"^^xsd:integer .
           
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504b a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem504 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "FAS Agenda line 2"^^xsd:string ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasOrdinalNumber "2"^^xsd:integer .           
                      
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504c a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem504 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "FAS Agenda line 3"^^xsd:string ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasOrdinalNumber "3"^^xsd:integer .
                      
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504d a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem504 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "FAS Agenda line 4"^^xsd:string ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasOrdinalNumber "4"^^xsd:integer .         
                      
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504e a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem504 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "FAS Agenda line 5"^^xsd:string ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasOrdinalNumber "5"^^xsd:integer .
                      
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504f a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem504 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "FAS Agenda line 6"^^xsd:string ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasOrdinalNumber "6"^^xsd:integer .
           
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem144 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem144 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "Y"^^xsd:string .
 
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem005 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem005 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "SF"^^xsd:string .

   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem102 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem102 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "S   881234"^^xsd:string .
 
   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem017 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem017 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasRawStringValue "C"^^xsd:string .
}
```

Second SPARQL Update query (instantiates the proposal which ties together the data items instantiated by the first query and runs the compliance check constructor... runs very slowly, around 20 seconds on my computer):

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sxxicc: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheck#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX sp: <http://spinrdf.org/sp#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX smf: <http://topbraid.org/sparqlmotionfunctions#>
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX spl: <http://spinrdf.org/spl#>
PREFIX spin: <http://spinrdf.org/spin#>
PREFIX arg: <http://spinrdf.org/arg#>
PREFIX SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals#>
PREFIX sxxicci: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

INSERT DATA
{

   sxxicci:TestPub7Proposal a sxxicc:Pub7Proposal ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem005 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem017 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem102 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem110 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem113 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem144 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem300 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem500 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem501 ; 
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem503 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504a ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504b ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504c ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504d ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504e ;
#           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem504f ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem511 .
 

}
```

This second query takes a long time to execute, around 20 seconds.  This is not consistent with the other compliance checks (not included in this RDF).  I've isolated this one rule from among 13 other similar rules (string parsing and comparisons mostly) because it dominates time consumption.

The (correct but delayed) results:

[image]

The SPIN constructor in question (for `sxxicc:Pub7Proposal` class):

```
# NEED MINUTE <M> NOTE M002 IN CIRCUIT REMARKS LISTING IRAC DOCUMENT GIVING APPROVAL FOR THIS ASSIGNMENT. (501 08)
CONSTRUCT {
    ?this sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasComplianceMessage "NEED MINUTE <M> NOTE M002 IN CIRCUIT REMARKS LISTING IRAC DOCUMENT GIVING APPROVAL FOR THIS ASSIGNMENT. (501 08)"^^xsd:string .
}
WHERE {
    ?this a sxxicc:Pub7Proposal .
    ?this sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem ?dataItem102 .
    ?dataItem102 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem102 .
    ?dataItem102 sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue ?serialNumString .
    ?this sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem ?dataItem500 .
    ?dataItem500 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem500 .
    ?dataItem500 sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue ?iracNotesString .
    ?this sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem ?dataItem501 .
    ?dataItem501 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem501 .
    ?dataItem501 sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue ?notesFreeTextCommentsString .
    ?this sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem ?dataItem113 .
    ?dataItem113 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem113 .
    ?dataItem113 sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue ?stationClassString .
    ?this sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem ?dataItem300 .
    ?dataItem300 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem300 .
    ?dataItem300 sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue ?stateCountryForTransmittingStation .
    BIND (SUBSTR(?serialNumString, 1, 4) AS ?orgString) .
    BIND (SUBSTR(?stationClassString, 1, 2) AS ?stationClassCode) .
    FILTER (((((?orgString = "S   "^^xsd:string) && (?iracNotesString = "S181"^^xsd:string)) && (?notesFreeTextCommentsString != "M002"^^xsd:string)) && (?stationClassCode = "FX"^^xsd:string)) && (?stateCountryForTransmittingStation = "DC"^^xsd:string)) .
}
```

Why does this constructor run so slowly on a modern PC (AMD quad core 2.3 GHz running Windows 8 with 16 GB physical memory and no significant additional application loading)?  Other constructors run quickly on the same machine and using the same facts doing apparently similar things.

Here's a Jave VisualVM Sampler output from executing this example:

[image]

The RDF4J org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.concurrent.locks.LockManager$1.release() and org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.concurrent.locks.LockManager.createLock() dominate the Self Time.  Why??  Is there something I can do to rewrite my rules to avoid this time consumption?

NOTES:

1. The first triple of the WHERE clause is not necessary in a SPIN constructor because ?this is set automatically.  However, I include it in order to ease debugging by copying this constructor into a SPARQL query (Explore/Query) in the workbench.  I also find it handy to replace the CONSTRUCT clause by "SELECT DISTINCT *" while leaving the WHERE clause in tact for constructor debugging.
2. The sole purpose of the WHERE clause in this constructor is to provide the graph pattern match that shows the error condition for the fixed error message in the CONSTRUCT clause exists.  No bindings carry over from the WHERE clause into the CONSTRUCT clause, but the WHERE clause still gates assertion of the triple in the CONSTRUCT clause.

**UPDATE**

I have modified the constructor by removing one FILTER and the associated triples from the constructor:

```
FILTER (?iracNotesString = "S181"^^xsd:string) .

?this sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem ?dataItem500 .
?dataItem500 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem500 .
?dataItem500 sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue ?iracNotesString .
```

This results in the constructor shown below in TBC FE:

[image]

Running the same test with the same 2 SPARQL update queries, the second query has a very non-linear reduction in execution time from over 20 seconds to under 2 seconds.  Again, this does not seem right.

Comment: I'm not understanding the purpose of your constructor.  In SPIN, the constructor is defined on the class, executed when an instance is created, with the created instance pre-bound to `?this`.  In your case, then, all you need is the CONSTRUCT clause.  The WHERE clause is not necessary as it doesn't contribute to the constructed triple.

Comment: @scotthenninger the CONSTRUCT is intentionally conditioned on the WHERE clause but does not use any bindings. The constructor is looking for violations a rule expressed in the WHERE clause with regard to the various data items. When this condition is violated, the constructor generates an error message in the CONSTRUCT. While it's true that the CONSTRUCT clause does not use any of the bindings from the WHERE clause, it's also true assertion of the triple in the CONSTRUCT clause remains conditioned on matching the graph pattern specified in the WHERE clause.

Comment: One might also think that I should be using SPIN constraints instead of constructors.  However, I need for the error/warning messages (such as the one in this constructor) to be asserted and accessible in the triple store.  Also, my experience in Sesame/RDF4J has been that a constraint violation blocks assertion of the class individual.  In my application the assertion should go forward.  This is especially important in the case of rules that just conditionally generate warnings.  With constructors, the individual is always asserted.

Comment: You can replace `ASK` with a `CONSTRUCT` in a SPIN constraint, at least in TopBraid Composer.  This would materialize the triples specified in your CONSTRUCT statement.  A constraint violation should not stop processing, just flag the violation.  But there remains some confusion on constructor vs. constraint.  The constructor is executed only when the class member is created.  And your `WHERE` clause can have no effect on the constructor you defined, unless the query fails to find a match - in which case no triples will be constructed.

Comment: Thanks @scotthenninger.  The sole effect I want from the WHERE clause is to find a match (assert the CONSTRUCT triple, an error message) or not find a match (this error not found, no triple, no error message).  That's all I want from the WHERE clause.  I had trouble with SPIN CONSTRUCT constraint under TBC Maestro Edition b/c the error message did not appear to be asserted in the default graph, which I wanted.  I switched over to constructors before switching to Sesame/RDF4J.  Constructors seem more general and serve my purposes.

Comment: As an update, the RDF4J developers have taken this up.  At their suggestion, I've tried the latest snapshot of RDF4J, but the problem persists.  I'll update this again with a solution when one is in hand.